# How can I prevent the second forms submit button from removing data from the first form while using the the window.history.pushState function?

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I was advised to use the windows.history.pushState function in order to be able to sustain the information the user enters into the text boxes and be able to use the browser's reload this page button if they elected to do so, this function works just fine with just one form, but I've added a second form and the submit button on the second form removes the data from the first form once the user presses it.

```
<?php
function getDistance($addressFrom, $addressTo, $unit){
    //Change address format
    $formattedAddrFrom = str_replace(' ','+',$addressFrom);
    $formattedAddrTo = str_replace(' ','+',$addressTo);

    //Send request and receive json data
    $geocodeFrom = file_get_contents('http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?
    address='.$formattedAddrFrom.'&sensor=false');
    $outputFrom = json_decode($geocodeFrom);
    $geocodeTo = file_get_contents('http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?
    address='.$formattedAddrTo.'&sensor=false');
    $outputTo = json_decode($geocodeTo);

    //Get latitude and longitude from geo data
    $latitudeFrom = $outputFrom->results[0]->geometry->location->lat;
    $longitudeFrom = $outputFrom->results[0]->geometry->location->lng;
    $latitudeTo = $outputTo->results[0]->geometry->location->lat;
    $longitudeTo = $outputTo->results[0]->geometry->location->lng;

    //Calculate distance from latitude and longitude
    $theta = $longitudeFrom - $longitudeTo;
    $dist = sin(deg2rad($latitudeFrom)) * sin(deg2rad($latitudeTo)) +
            cos(deg2rad($latitudeFrom)) * cos(deg2rad($latitudeTo)) *
            cos(deg2rad($theta));
    $dist = acos($dist);
    $dist = rad2deg($dist);
    $miles = $dist * 60 * 1.8515;
    $unit = strtoupper($unit);
    if ($unit == "K") {
        return round($miles * 1.609344, PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP).' km';
    } 
    else if ($unit == "N") {
        return round($miles * 0.8677, PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP).'';
    } 
    else {
        return round ($miles).'';
    }
}

$distanceTotal = null;
$addressFrom = null;
$addressTo = null;

if(!empty($_GET['addrFrom'])) { 
    $addressFrom = $_GET['addrFrom']; 
}
if(!empty($_GET['addrTo'])) { 
    $addressTo = $_GET['addrTo']; 
}
if(!empty($_GET['distanceTotal'])) { 
    $distanceTotal = $_GET['distanceTotal']; 
}

if (!empty($_GET['addrFrom']) && !empty($_GET['addrTo'])) {
    $distanceTotal = getDistance($addressFrom, $addressTo, "N");
    $distanceTotal = sprintf('%0.2f',round($distanceTotal,2));  
}
$success = false;   

?>
<?php

$selected='';

function get_options($select){   
    $rate=array('Economic Rate'=>3.00,'Standard Rate'=>4.00,'Express 
    Rate'=>5.00,'Quantumtheory'=>6.00);
    $option='3.00';

foreach ($rate as $key_rate => $value_rate){
    if($select==$value_rate){
         $option.='<option value="'.$value_rate.'"selected>'.$key_rate.'</option>';
    }
    else{       
         $option.='<option value="'.$value_rate.'">'.$key_rate.'</option>'; 
    }
}
return $option;
}

if(isset($_POST['rate'])){
    $selected=number_format((float)$_POST ['rate'], 2,'.','');  
}

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <div align="center">
        <script>
            if(typeof window.history.pushState == 'function') {
                window.history.pushState({}, "Hide", "<?php echo 
        $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>");
            }
        </script>  
        <form method="get" name"lion" id"blue" >  
            <p class="distanceTotal">
                <div id="d">
                    <p><b>Adress From<b>
                        <input type="text" name="addrFrom" id"fred" value="<?php echo $addressFrom; 
                        ?>" />
                    </p>
                    <p><label>Adress To</label><b>
                        <input type="text" name="addrTo" id="chris" value="<?php echo $addressTo; ?
                        >" />
                    </p>
                    <label>Total Miles<label><b> 
                    <input type="text" id="distanceTotal" name="distanceTotal" value="<?php echo 
                    $distanceTotal; ?>" >
                    <p>
                        <input type="submit" name="calc_1" value="Calculate Distance" />
                    </p>
                </div>  
            </p>
        </form>

        <form method="POST" name"tiger" id="black"  />
            <p>
                <div>
                    <select name="rate">
                    <option value="<?php echo get_options($selected); ?>" /></option>
                    </select>
                    <input type='submit' id='submit_2' name="calc_2" value='Submit' />
                    <input type="text" id="rateTotal" name="rat" width="110px" value="<?php echo 
                    $selected; ?>" /><b><b><label>Per Mile</label>
                </div>  
            </p>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: if i reload a page i expect the form data to reset, probably why i reloaded in the first place.

Comment: The page is reloading when the user presses submit !

Comment: ok? and? whats the need to refill it?, if its been sent i would expect perhaps a message saying so and then the form again if that's what you want, or redirect to another page.

Comment: When the user presses the first submit button everything is fine but when the user presses the second submit button pressing the second button causes the all of the previously imputed data to disappear.

Comment: ahh ok that's clearer, I would just use one form rather than two

Comment: We want the information that was imputed into the previous text box to remain unless the user chooses to use the browsers reload this page button or reset the page, it's being removed upon submit we don't want that.

Comment: you can do that with one form as you have the data and can repopulate it

Comment: Okay I don't mind doing like that but if I modify the current code and make it one form, the first submit button causes the first and the second answer to post at the same time instead of just posting the first answer until the user decides to press the second submit button and then post the second answer.

Comment: How could I assign these submit buttons to post an answer for a particular input without affecting another and causing the other to post at the same time?